# vga connected to built-in motherboard but GPU still running?

Tags: graphics-card

Decided to buy a GTX 1050ti Palit 4gb but I don't have the HDMI to VGA active adapter so i decided to put it on my motherboard in-case i got one then put my VGA adapter to my built-in motherboard the thing is I accidentally open my PUBG then strange coz I'm running 60fps+ while using HD graphics card then i notice the fan of 1050ti is running. should i remove it until i have an active adapter or something?

Comment: Yes, the system is still communicating with the new GPU, and energy is still being sent to the fan. That's entirely normal. Is there a reason you DO NOT think the discrete GPU should be active?